# rails actionview: How to "not show" attributes if receiving nil or something else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionviewhelper

Is there an easy way to remove options attributes for the `tag` or `content_tag` helper?

```
<%= content_tag :div, content, {
  class: 'content',
  style: styles_hash.map{|x| "#{x[0].underscore.dasherize}: #{x[1]}"}.join('; '),
  data: {
    hyperlink: (hyperlink if hyperlink.present?)
  }
} %>
```

In this example, I'm wondering how to remove the `data-hyperlink`. Even if I throw a `nil` or `false` it stills displays as either `data-hyperlink="null"` or `data-hyperlink="false"` respectively. I need it to not display entirely if not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten a solution like this but I'd like to know if there is any better, or inside that `data` attribute?

```
<%= content_tag :div, content, {
  class: 'content',
  style: styles_hash.map{|x| "#{x[0].underscore.dasherize}: #{x[1]}"}.join('; '),
  'data-hyperlink' => (hyperlink if hyperlink.present?)
} %>
```